# Is there a search for docker images based on their content?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Let me start with the preface that I'm pretty new to the docker world.

I've found myself (and colleagues) searching for docker images on several occasions, where we looked for any docker image that contains specific binaries. E.g. we want to run selenium-based tests in an headless Chrome, so we look for an image that contains node, Chrome and selenium.

This kind of search, at least in what I've experienced, is not well supported by dockerhub. You can search there for all ingredients separately, and find great images for them. But you don't find images containing all ingredients at once.

*Am I missing an obvious place to look for?*

Needless to say we want to avoid creating our own images if we can, as we would have to maintain them in the long run, and we were of the impression that we couldn't be the first ones needing a similar image.

Comment: `docker search node | grep -i chrome | grep -i selenium` in Terminal maybe?

Comment: Note that the usual pattern for Docker is for a container to run _one_ thing.  So you'll find a multitude of Node images, and several PostgreSQL images, but not a well-maintained combined Node+PostgreSQL image, for example.  You can use tools like [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to run multiple containers in a combined application.